# How to extract specified text from columns in Excel

Tags: python, excel, powerquery, data-cleaning, rscript

I have tried numerous ways but have failed to get the right data to the new columns.

The column description contains a lot of information in which I want to extract to separate columns. Examples

`Aged Care HCP - 29/6/2021 - Social Support Weekday 7am – 7pm 9:00AM 12:00PM`

I want to extract the above to the below Columns:

| Sector | Date | Support Schedule | Day | Day time | Shift Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aged Care HCP | 29/06/2021 | Social Support | Weekday | 7am - 7pm | 09:00am - 12:00pm |

Can anyone please guide me or provide me the solution on how I can clean the data to the above said columns? I have attached the data for your perusal.

I have tried using excel power query

Below is the link for the document
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/4o09adq936cc7cls28sfz/Worksheet.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=zalomc9pagexd435z014q6qjc

Comment: What would distinguish the column breaks in the continuous text? For example, are the number of words always the same? Or could Weekday 7am - 7pm become Monday 7am - 7pm, Tuesday 3-4 or something else?

Comment: @horseyride please find the below link, it consists of all the different variations possible
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/4o09adq936cc7cls28sfz/Worksheet.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=zalomc9pagexd435z014q6qjc

Comment: sorry, I am unable to access dropbox. Please post to a public viewing area or paste in initial question

Comment: I started coding a VBA solution for you so that you can have a button in the workbook but I noticed that the information dividers follow an irregular format eg. `7am-7pm` versus `9:00am 12:00pm` with no break between `Social Support Weekday 7am` as examples. I think the first step would be ensuring a standard of data entry so that it can be managed programmatically. I'm sure there are people out there smarter than me who could manage it but there is a reason why process is important.

Comment: Just checking in to see if you have found a solution to your query yet..
Have you found a way to ensure the data entered is of a consistent form?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult with unstructured data, but here's an example in Power Query of how you can parse some of it out. Depending on the actual data and variety, you will have to tweak it.

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Sample.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Sheet1_Sheet,{{"Column1", type any}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type any}, {"Column6", type any}, {"Column7", type any}, {"Column8", type any}, {"Column9", type any}, {"Column10", type text}, {"Column11", type text}}),
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Changed Type",4),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Top Rows", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Date", type any}, {"Source", type text}, {"Description", type text}, {"Reference", type text}, {"Debit", type number}, {"Credit", type number}, {"Running Balance", type number}, {"Gross", type number}, {"GST", type number}, {"Account Code", Int64.Type}, {"Department", type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type1", each ([Description] <> null)),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each Text.StartsWith([Description], "Aged Care HCP")),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Filtered Rows1", "Description", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("-", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Sector", "Service Date", "Description"}),
    #"Changed Type with Locale" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter", {{"Service Date", type date}}, "en-GB"),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type with Locale","Weekday","|Weekday|",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Description"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Replaced Value", "Description", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Support Schedule", "Day", "Description"}),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Split Column by Delimiter1"," – ","–",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Description"}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value1",{{"Description", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter2" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Trimmed Text", "Description", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Day time", "Shift Time"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter2",{{"Sector", type text}, {"Support Schedule", type text}, {"Day", type text}, {"Day time", type text}, {"Shift Time", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type2"
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score -1):

use pandas https://pypi.org/project/pandas/

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

# will print the column
print(df.col_name)
```

Comment: I'm actually referring to extracting text from one single column and then dividing as per the defined above. If possible, please refer to the link which contains of the worksheet